# MySQL Combine Data + Count(*) Query FROM 2 tables

Tags: mysql, select

I need help with an query. I have a 'members' table and a 'comments' table.

```
members:  userid,name,bday  etc...
comments: id,userid,message,rel  etc...
```

Untill now i used 2 queries for membersdata and commentsCount, and combined both in PHP.

My Question. Is it possible to get both (all from members && count of comments) in only one query?

This is not workung...

```
SELECT members.*, count(comments.*) as count 
FROM members, comments 
WHERE members.userid=comments.userid 
group by members.userid
```

Does somebody know an other solution?

Comment: Why isn't it working? Syntax error? Or what does it return?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaned-up version of your query, assuming you want the `userid` and `number of comments` for each:

```
SELECT members.userid, count(*) as count 
FROM members
INNER JOIN comments 
ON members.userid = comments.userid 
GROUP BY members.userid
```

The issues I addressed:

1. only selected columns that are either in the `group by` clause, or have an aggregate function applied to them.  It is incorrect to select columns which don't satisfy either of those criteria (although MySQL allows you to do it)
2. replaced implicit join with explicit join, and moved join condition from `where` clause to `on` clause
3. replaced `select ... count(comments.*)` with `select ... count(*)`.  `count(*)` works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Matt
I used your version. And im learning by the was sql-joins.

The problem with my code was the 'count(comments.*)'. Mysql does not like this!

This is working:

```
SELECT members.*, count(comments.rel) as count 
FROM members, comments 
WHERE members.userid=comments.userid 
group by members.userid
```